# How to create a Facebook app to grant access to my fan page's insights?

Tags: php, facebook, api

Hello I am really new on Facebook API.

I found this url ( https://graph.facebook.com/page_id_goes_here/insights/page_fans )that shows you insights of your page. When I put it a page id, I get this "An access token is required to request this resource."

How can I create that application needed to grant access with a token to my page?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

https://dev.twitter.com/docs

Get the PHP SDK

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Then you can look how to do stuff like get an access token: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getAccessToken/

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have changed the question to something more specific.

Comment: Added where you ca nfind that info out.